# How to make a browser extension open new web page and put text in form

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I want to make a browser extension so the user can select some text and be presented with an option which, if they click it, opens google translate web page with the selected text in the input field and the 'Translate' button activated so the translation is now in the appropriate field.

I have not made a browser extension before but have some html and javascript knowledge.

This is an initial query because I want to start coding it with a feasible approach in mind.